# How to create an Array of Strings in Objective c for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to create an array of strings that can be randomized and limited to a certain x number of strings.

If the array could be randomized I could pick the first x strings and that would work fine.

I'm trying to use code like this currently

```
NSString *statements[9];
statements[0] = @"hello";
```

This seems to work but the array seems to be full of rubbish data.

Can someone help me in the right direction. (is the memory allocation being done in the wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Do you want an array with nine strings in it?

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", nil]
```

Comment: Don't forget to end your array with nil.

@"lastString", nil];

(it may just be my iPhone that isn't showing me the end or you statement.

Comment: Why end it with nil?

Answer (score 64):

As of Xcode 4.4, you can use Array Literals, which are much cleaner and easier to read. You no longer need to include 'nil'. For example:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5"];
```

Answer (score 2):

All C auto arrays like that will be full of garbage until you fill them. As long as it isn't getting filled with garbage later, everything is working as expected. However, Cocoa includes the NSArray class which is more common to use for arrays of objects (since it does proper memory management and works with the rest of the framework and all that).

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip, it's not necessary to shuffle the contents of the array.  Just randomize the access.  For each card you want to pick from the deck, pick a random number and select the card at that index.  Then, take the top card and place it where the card you just picked was.

If you *really* want to sort the array though, you can do it with very little code using -`sortedArrayUsingSelector:` where your comparison method returns `NSOrderedAscending` or `NSOrderedDescending` randomly.