# How to declare empty arrays using objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I have my code in java as follows but I don't know how to convert it.

```
public  int[] originalPixels;
public  int[][] RGB1;
public  int[][] RGB2;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize an empty mutable array in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224762/how-to-initialize-an-empty-mutable-array-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what exactly you want to achieve you can create a property of type NSArray (if it doesn't have to be mutable) or NSMutableArray if you want to modify that array. You could also you a C style of arrays but I think the object version is more convenient and Objective-C world.

This is very basic problem so I would recommend you to read some tutorial with basis of objective-C as there is quite a lot of details you should be aware to fits your demands :)

Some helpful links:

- [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602572/how-to-create-an-array-of-strings-in-objective-c-for-iphone)
- [second](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsarray.html)
- [third](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_arrays.htm)
- [fourth](http://www.raywenderlich.com/40293/learn-to-code-ios-apps-2-strings-arrays-objects-and-classes)

Answer (score 0):

The c/c++ is more closer to hardware than java. The array is mean the postion of the memory.
So you can use pointers. int*  originalPixels; or  int** RGB1; int** RGB2; 
After the declare you sholud allocate them.